# HttpClient.Timeout configured by AddHttpClient is ignored

Tags: .net-core, httpclientfactory

When using the recommended `AddHttpClient` extension to configure the `IHttpClientFactory` and include some default `HttpClient` setup, the value I set for the `Timeout` property is not seen in the `HttpClient` instances that I subsequently create.

Demo uses Azure Function, which is like ASP.NET Core.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public static readonly int PushTimeoutMs = 3000;

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("PushNotification", client =>
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(PushTimeoutMs);
        });
    }
}
```

Creating the client.

```
public class TestFunctionTwo
{
    public TestFunctionTwo(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.HttpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    //

    public IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory { get; }

    //

    [FunctionName("TestFunctionTwo")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        return new OkObjectResult($"OK - Timeout: {this.HttpClientFactory.CreateClient().Timeout.TotalMilliseconds}");
    }
}
```

Returns

```
OK - Timeout: 100000
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you need to create an `HttpClient` of the same name as the one you've configured, i.e. `"PushNotification"`.

```
return new OkObjectResult($"OK - Timeout: {this.HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("PushNotification").Timeout.TotalMilliseconds}");
```

Answer (score 0):

For me we just use the connection for one api client, so we just register it like this:

```
            services.AddHttpClient<IMyApiClient, MyApiClient>(httpClient =>
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(hostContext.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MyApiUrl"));
                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(hostContext.Configuration.GetValue<int>("MyApiTimeoutSeconds"));
            });
```